# How to replace a block on the whole site. Magento

Tags: magento

I created my custom block which should replace an existing Magento block.
Wanna to replace the existing Magento block with my block on the whole site, independetly upon the page and the place where the existing Magento block exists. What should be the reference ?
Actually I have something like this:

```
<default>
<reference name="left">
    <remove name="left.newsletter" />
        <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="newsletter" after="-" template="mynewsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
</reference>
</default>
```

I remove there the default newsletter on the left and then create my newsletter block. It works but replaces only the newsletter block on the left. Wanna to use my block on the whole site in place of left.newsletter even if the block is in other references like content or right etc. What should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace every occurance of `Mage_Newsletter_Block_Subscribe` with your own block `My_Module_Block_Subscribe`, use a class rewrite. In your modules **config.xml**:

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <newsletter>
            <rewrite>
                <subscribe>My_Module_Block_Subscribe</subscribe>
            </rewrite>
        </newsletter>
    </block>
</global>
```

But judging by your code, you actually do not have a custom block, just a custom template. You could change the template with an observer for the `core_block_tohtml_before` event, that calls `setTemplate('mynewsletter/subscribe.phtml')` on the block if its class is `Mage_Newsletter_Block_Subscribe`.